# Chrome Extension Messaging Architecture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I recently got started on developing my first Chrome extension, mostly just to see if I could do it, and I got to wondering about the mechanics behind how exactly messages are passed around. This may turn out to be a more general question about the [windows.postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.postmessage), but I was wondering if someone could explain the behind-the-scenes processes that control the receipt and propagation of messages.

This is my current understanding of messaging w.r.t Chrome extensions:

- There are four classes of Javascript: `(1)` JS tied to the popup, `(2)` JS running in the background or as an event, `(3)` JS in content scripts, and `(4)` JS injected into the page.
- `(2) -> (1)` and `(3) -> (1)` are sent by `runtime.sendMessage()`. They're only received when the popup is open.
- `(1) -> (2)` and `(3) -> (2)` are sent by `runtime.sendMessage()` or `tabs.sendMessage()` from `(3)` and `(1)` respectively. They're received ASAP, because background/event JS is persistent (I'm not quite sure if that's the right word, since event JS has to be tied into eventListeners).
- `(1) -> (3)` and `(2) -> (3)` are sent by `tabs.sendMessage()`. They're received ASAP, since the content script is active as long as the webpage is (since it exists in a parallel sandbox).
- `(*) -> (4)` and `(4) -> (*)` can't be handled by `chrome.*` for security issues, but `(3) -> (4)` and `(4) -> (3)` can be handled by `window.postMessage()`, since they both exist within the context of the webpage.

There's a couple of things I have questions about specifically - the first one being, of course, if I've even described things correctly. The others are these:

- What exactly is the distinction between `runtime.sendMessage()` and `tabs.sendMessage()` that dictates which JS can actually use them?
- How do messages get passed around? What happens in the background when `*.sendMessage()` or `window.postMessage()` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - There are four classes of Javascript: `(1)` JS tied to the popup, `(2)` JS running in the background or as an event, `(3)` JS in content scripts, and `(4)` JS injected into the page.

`(1)` and `(2)` are actually the same ("popup" also falls under "extension code" - see [Contexts and methods for communication between the browser action, background scripts, and content scripts of chrome extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246133/contexts-and-methods-for-communication-between-the-browser-action-background-sc/17276475#17276475)).

> - `(2) -> (1)` and `(3) -> (1)` are sent by `runtime.sendMessage()`. They're only received when the popup is open.
> - `(1) -> (2)` and `(3) -> (2)` are sent by `runtime.sendMessage()` or `tabs.sendMessage()` from `(3)` and `(1)` respectively. They're received ASAP, because background/event JS is persistent (I'm not quite sure if that's the right word, since event JS has to be tied into eventListeners).

`runtime.sendMessage` can indeed be sent by `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)`. In the role of a receiver, there is no special difference between `(1)` and `(2)`. Here is where [my classification of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246133/contexts-and-methods-for-communication-between-the-browser-action-background-sc/17276475#17276475) comes in: A message sent by `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is received by extension code, except for the frame of the sender. For instance, if you put an `<iframe>` in the background page and call `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from the background page, `chrome.runtime.onMessage` is going to be triggered in that frame.

When [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) are in use, the message event is only dispatched after having waited for the event page to load.

> - `(1) -> (3)` and `(2) -> (3)` are sent by `tabs.sendMessage()`. They're received ASAP, since the content script is active as long as the webpage is (since it exists in a parallel sandbox).

`chrome.tabs.sendMessage` makes sense as long as you have a valid tab ID. Since background pages have no tab ID, it's not possible to send a message to a background page using `tabs.sendMessage`. Content scripts, extension pages in tabs, extension frames in tabs can all receive messages that are sent by `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, since they are part of the tab.

> - `(*) -> (4)` and `(4) -> (*)` can't be handled by `chrome.*` for security issues, but `(3) -> (4)` and `(4) -> (3)` can be handled by `window.postMessage()`, since they both exist within the context of the webpage.

`(4) -> (1,2)` (web page to extension code) is possible via [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable).

And `(4) -> (4)` is also possible with `window.postMessage`, but not directly with `*.sendMessage` (because this excludes the sender).

> - What exactly is the distinction between `runtime.sendMessage()` and `tabs.sendMessage()` that dictates which JS can actually use them?

`tabs.sendMessage` can only be used when the tabs API is available, to send a message to tabs, whereas `runtime.sendMessage` can also be used by content scripts.

Succintly, use `tabs.sendMessage` to send messages to a tab, use `runtime.sendMessage` to send messages to another part of your extension.

> - How do messages get passed around? What happens in the background when `*.sendMessage()` or `window.postMessage()` is called?

- `window.postMessage` has exactly one receiver, i.e. the [`message` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#The_dispatched_event) is called only once. `*.sendMessage` has zero or more receivers (if you use [`tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage), then you can restrict this to one by setting the `frameId` parameter), so [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) could be called multiple times (once for every frame).
- If you are not careful, you can accidentally leak information to untrusted scripts via `window.postMessage`. Make sure that you validate all messages in both directions (from and to the web page) - see the [Window.postMessage#Security concerns article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Security_concerns) for more info.  `*.sendMessage` only passes messages around within your extension, so that is generally safe.
- `*.sendMessage` messages are [JSON-serialized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description), which is much more restricted than the [structured cloning algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) as used by postMessage.
- `*.sendMessage` always requires at least two [IPC messages](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication) (sender to browser process, browser process to every receiver). `postMessage` can be handled more efficiently, since the messages are dealt with within the same renderer process.
  **This is an internal implementation detail**, and is not guaranteed to hold in the future. What it means in practice is that if you send lots of data around, and profile the performance, then you will most likely observe more issues with `*.sendMessage` than `window.postMessage` (for a one-sided benchmark, see e.g. [Is there a size limit like 32bytes or 64Bytes? for message passing between content scripts and background pages for chrome extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925936/is-there-a-size-limit-like-32bytes-or-64bytes-for-message-passing-between-conte)).
- `*.sendMessage(any message, optional function responseCallback)` is internally implemented as something that is equivalent to
  calling [`chrome.runtime.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect) (or [`chrome.tabs.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-connect)), registering `responseCallback` using `port.onMessage.addListener` and then disconnecting the port (immediately if no callback is set, otherwise only after the callback was called).

  `window.postMessage` [queues a message](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#dom-window-postmessage). The queue is not immediately drained, but the message event is dispatched "as soon as possible".

Comment: Rob W - have you ever tried comparing the performance of window.postMessage with the native Chrome extension messaging?