# Storing large Array in chrome.storage crashes ChromeApp

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-app

So I am making a chrome application and using the

```
chrome.storage.local.set
```

I have the 'unlimitedStorage' and 'storage' permissions set and the code I have works just fine with small amounts of videos and images. But as soon as I increase this amount, even slightly (Maybe going from 40MB to 80MB) it crashes the application when it tries to store.

Has anyone experienced this, as I understood it since I have the unlimitedStorage permission it shouldn't be a size issue, or is there still a limit in chrome.storage for a single item?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you safely storing an AoO as a string? i suspect as JSON, and the V8 implementation  doesn't like anything anything bigger than a couple dozen MB (seems to increase over time, 10MB used to crash it...)

Comment: No thats not what I meant sorry, I'm storying images and video inside of objects as Base64 encoded URI's. And then storing the objects into an array.

Comment: you could probably store the long base64 strings directly under unique key names

Comment: Yah that was exactly my next course of action. Was just seeing if there was something I was missing with this. Thanks though.

Comment: For large objects one should use WebSQL or IndexedDB.

Comment: Can I use WebSQL or indexedDB in chromeApps?

Comment: See also [Is there a size limit like 32bytes or 64Bytes? for message passing between content scripts and background pages for chrome extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31928402)

Comment: IndexedDB can be used in packaged apps https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps